# How to export an illustrator artboard in two sections?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, export

[image]

I've tried reading similar answers about exporting to different sizes, but I'm still a bit confused.

What I'm trying to do is to optimize my process of creating header images for my blog. For each post, I want to generate 2 images, one 800 x 800 with a link to my website (what I've labeled INSTAGRAM) and another 1200 x 627 without the link (FACEBOOK).

I've tried playing with `Save for web`, but I currently have to hide the instagram layer, save as transparent png and do the reverse for the other image. Is there an easier way? Maybe using multiple artboards, or slices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: Use multiple overlapping artboards.

You can either use the artboard tool to create your artboards or use existing shapes to create them by going to *Object → Artboards → Convert to Artboards* with your shapes selected.

Use *File → Export* to save your artwork. Make sure to check "Use Artboards" and it will export a file for each artboard. It's a good idea to name your artboards (see the Artboards panel in my example), your file names will then automatically be apended with that name.

[image: Multiple artboards]

Comment: Nice. I think I tried this, but wasn't able to use it because you can't choose the artboard when doing `Save for Web` and I wanted to control the dimensions without having to rely on the dpi. Am I missing an obvious way of doing this?

Comment: As long as you export at 72ppi then the dimensions are the same as your artwork so that shouldn't be an issue as long as you set everything up at the correct size